# Programmatically Add Row to Linq-to-SQL Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Let's say we generate this link-to-sql dataset for a grid:

```
var query = from c in customers
                    orderby c.FirstName
                    select c;

Grid1.DataSet = query;
Grid1.DataBind();
```

After generating this dataset, we need to programmatically add "Vince Vaughn" to this dataset (the goal is to add a row to this linq-to-sql dataset so that the values obtained from the database, and the 1 row that was programmatically added, all appear in the grid).

How would be accomplish this programmatically using C#? (i.e. programmatically add a row for Vince Vaughn to the dataset)

```
CUSTOMERS TABLE
ID     FirstName    LastName    
1      John         Jones    
2      Sally        Smith
```

Environment: C#.NET 4.0

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `.ToList()` on the query and then `list.Add(new Customer {...})`

Answer (score 4):

If you mean actually add the row to the back end storage and, assuming `ID` is an identity column and your model is correctly configured you can do.

```
using (var context =  new ...)
{
    context.customers.Add(
        new Customer { FirstName = "Vince", LastName = "Vaughn" });
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

If you just want Vince to appear as if he is in the list you could do

```
var query = customers.Concat(new Customer[]
    { 
        new Customer
            {
                ID = customers.Max(c => c.ID) + 1,
                FirstName = "Vince",
                LastName = "Vaughn"
            }
    }).OrderBy(c => c.FirstName);
```

That would add Vince to the list without actually adding him to the storage.

---

If you just want to "spoof" a result or results into a set from a database you could concatentate with a set of a compatible anonymous type, somthing like this ...

```
var queryWithVince = query.Select(r = new 
                    { 
                        FirstName = r.FirstName, 
                        LastName = r.LastName
                    })
    .Concat( new []
        {
            new { FirstName = "Vince", LastName = "Vaughn" }
        }
    .OrderBy(p => p.FirstName);
```

Two anonymous types are compatible if thier members have the same property names and types. If the result of `query` is some other non anonymous type you'll need to ensure that the linq processing is able to combine those results with your anonymous additions.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply.  Any idea how one would add a row to an existing query (like adding a row to the query variable above).  My Linq query is actually a little more complex than the one I gave in the example, and joins from lots of other tables.  Basically, I need to add a row to this generic compilation of data (it's not of any class type (like customer in the original example).

Comment: It must be of some anonymous type then right? I'll extend my answer.

Comment: @user1410913 answer extended.

Answer (score 0):

if `Grid1.DataSet` is of type `IEnumerable<T>` and *not* of [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) type, there is no much options like

- requery all data again from data-base and re-assign it to a control
- cach first query data in `List<T>`, and after query only "new" data form data-base and add it to the binded list.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it myself but this might work. You could use a `DataTable` as repository, [add the row manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56.aspx) and then use it as DataSource for the `GridView`.

You can use this method to convert the `Linq.DataContext`  to a `DataTable`:

```
public DataTable ToDataTable(System.Data.Linq.DataContext ctx, object query)
{
     if (query == null)
     {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("query");
     }

     IDbCommand cmd = ctx.GetCommand(query as IQueryable);
     SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
     adapter.SelectCommand = (SqlCommand)cmd;
     DataTable dt = new DataTable("sd");

     try
     {
          cmd.Connection.Open();
          adapter.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source); 
          adapter.Fill(dt);
     }
     finally
     {
          cmd.Connection.Close();
     }
     return dt;
}
```

http://www.thejackol.com/2009/06/02/get-linq-to-sql-results-into-a-datatable/

Answer (score 0):

```
    customers.Add(new Customer {FirstName = "Vaughn" LastName="Vince"});

you can also add a new datarow to your dataset

DataRow row  = ds.Table["customer"].NewRow();
row["FirstName"] = "Vince";
row["LastName"] = "VMDFJM";
```